# Monopoly Money Tracker

Tags: javascript, python, html

I've downloaded a Monopoly money tracker, so me and a couple of friends can have a game over Skype and all be able to see what's actually happening with the game's funds.

I got it from here https://github.com/brentvollebregt/monopoly-money

If has the option to set each player's balance, but it doesn't work. It merely sets the balance of the player who is playing as the banker, regardles off which player you select. It also does it if you try and send the contents of the free parking square.

Here is the javascript handling the transactions

```
var background_check_delay = 4000

switch_balance_format = function(obj){
        var MK = obj.text.slice(-1);
        if (MK == "M"){
            obj.text = String(Number(obj.text.slice(0,-1)) * 1000) + "K"
        } else {
            obj.text = String(Number(obj.text.slice(0,-1)) / 1000) + "M"
        }
    };

switch_char = function(obj){
    var MK = obj.text
    if (MK == "M"){
    obj.text = "K"
    } else {
        obj.text = "M"
    }
}

flash_red = function() {
    $("#pin").css("background", "rgba(224, 31, 31,0.35)");
    $('#pin').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function()
    {
        $(this).css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.05)');
    }).delay(1000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
}

play_refresh = function(){
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/play_data/', function(data) {

        if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){
            window.location.reload(true);
            return;
        }

        if ($('#balance').text().slice(-1) == "K"){
            $('#balance').text(String(data['balance']) + "K");
        } else {
            $('#balance').text(String(data['balance']/1000) + "M");
        }

        var current_names = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#send_money_player').children().length; i++) {
            current_names.push($('#send_money_player').children()[i].text);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data['users'].length; i++) {
            if (!(current_names.indexOf(data['users'][i]) >= 0)){
                $('#send_money_player').append('<option value="' + data['users'][i] + '">' + data['users'][i] + '</option>')
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#send_money_player').children().length; i++) {
            if (["Bank", "Free Parking", "Player"].indexOf($('#send_money_player').children()[i].text) !== -1){
                continue;
            }
            if (data['users'].indexOf($('#send_money_player').children()[i].text) == -1){
                $('#send_money_player').children()[i].remove();
            }
        }

        if ($('#free_parking').text().slice(-1) == "K"){
            $('#free_parking').text(String(data['free_parking']) + "K");
        } else {
            $('#free_parking').text(String(data['free_parking']/1000) + "M");
        }

        var current_logs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#logs').children().length; i++) {
            current_logs.push($('#logs').children()[i].textContent );
        }
        data['logs'] = data['logs'];
        for (var i = 0; i < data['logs'].length; i++) {
            if (!(current_logs.indexOf(data['logs'][i]) >= 0)){
                $('#logs').prepend('<div class="play_scroll_log">' + data['logs'][i] + '</div>');
            }
        }
    });
}

bank_refresh = function(){
    $.get($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/bank_data/', function(data) {

        if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){
            window.location.reload(true);
            return;
        }

        if ($('#free_parking').text().slice(-1) == "K"){
            $('#free_parking').text("Amount: " + String(data['free_parking']) + "K");
        } else {
            $('#free_parking').text("Amount: " + String(data['free_parking']/1000) + "M");
        }

        var current_names = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#send_money_player').children().length; i++) {
            current_names.push($('#send_money_player').children()[i].text);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data['users'].length; i++) {
            if (!(current_names.indexOf(data['users'][i]) >= 0)){
                $('#send_money_player').append('<option value="' + data['users'][i] + '">' + data['users'][i] + '</option>')
                $('#send_free_parking_player').append('<option value="' + data['users'][i] + '">' + data['users'][i] + '</option>')
                $('#set_player_bal_player').append('<option value="' + data['users'][i] + '">' + data['users'][i] + '</option>')
                $('#active_players').append('<div style="width: 100%; height: 30%; display: block;"><div style="width: 50%; height: 100%; margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 0px; float: left;"><div class="outer_rel"><div class="middle"><div class="inner"><a class="white_text" style="font-size: 350%; float: left;">' + data['users'][i] + '</a></div></div></div></div><div style="width: 10%; height: 100%; float: right; margin-right: 15%;"><img onclick="javascript:remove_player(this);" value="' + data['users'][i] + '" src="' + close_png_src +'" style="height: 100%;"></div><div style="width: 10%; height: 100%; float: right;"><img onclick="javascript:edit_player_name(this);" value="' + data['users'][i] + '" src="' + edit_png_src +'" class="banker_switch"></div></div>')
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#send_money_player').children().length; i++) {
            if (["Bank", "Free Parking", "Player"].indexOf($('#send_money_player').children()[i].text) !== -1){
                continue;
            }
            var name = $('#send_money_player').children()[i].text
            if (data['users'].indexOf(name) == -1){
                $('#send_money_player').children()[i].remove();
                for (var i = 0; i < $('#send_free_parking_player').children().length; i++){
                    if ($('#send_free_parking_player').children()[i].text == name){
                        $('#send_free_parking_player').children()[i].remove()
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < $('#set_player_bal_player').children().length; i++){
                    if ($('#set_player_bal_player').children()[i].text == name){
                        $('#set_player_bal_player').children()[i].remove()
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < $('#active_players').children().length; i++){
                    if ($($('#active_players').children()[i]).find('a').text() == name){
                        $('#active_players').children()[i].remove()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (data['open']){
            if($('#lock_button').text() == "Closed"){
                $('#lock_button').text("Open");
            }
        } else {
            if($('#lock_button').text() == "Open"){
                $('#lock_button').text("Closed");
            }
        }
    });
}

leave = function(){
    window.location.href = $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/clear';
}

leave_prep = function(context){
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to " + context)){
        leave();
    }
}

check_pin_response = function(data){
    if (data['response'] == 1) {
        window.location.href = $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/game/';
    } else if (data['response'] == 3) {
        $('#pin').val('');
        flash_red();
    } else if (data['response'] == 4) {
        $('#pin').val('');
        alert("Game is currently locked");
        flash_red();
    } else if (data['response'] == 5) {
        $('#pin').val('');
        alert("Name is already taken");
        flash_red();
    }
}

who_starts_first = function(){
    $.get($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/who_starts/', function(data) {
        alert(data['user'] + " starts");
    });
}

play_background_checks = function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        play_refresh();
    }, background_check_delay);
}

bank_background_checks = function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        bank_refresh();
    }, background_check_delay);
}

edit_player_name = function(obj){
    var new_name = prompt("New name for " + $(obj).attr('value') + "?");
    if (!(new_name == "" || new_name == null)){
        $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/edit_player_name/', {
            player_name_to_change: $(obj).attr('value'),
            new_name: new_name
        });
    }

    bank_refresh();
}

remove_player = function(obj){
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to remove " + $(obj).attr('value') + "?")){
        $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/remove_player/', {
            player_name_to_remove: $(obj).attr('value')
        });
    }

    bank_refresh();
}

send_money = function(isBank){
    if($('#send_money_amount').val() == ""){
        alert("No amount entered");
        return;
    }
    if($('#send_money_player').val() == null){
        alert("No player selected");
        return;
    }

    if ($('#send_money_MK').text() == "K"){
        var amount = Number($('#send_money_amount').val())
    } else {
        var amount = Number($('#send_money_amount').val()*1000)
    }
    var player = $('#send_money_player').val()

    var success = true;
    $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/send_money/', {
        transfer_amount: amount,
        player_receiving: player,
        banker: isBank
    }, function(data){
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (!(response['success'])){
            alert(response['reason']);
            success = false;
        }
    });

    if (!success){
        return;
    }

    $('#send_money_player').val("")
    $('#send_money_amount').val("")

    if (window.location['pathname'] == "/bank/"){
        bank_refresh();
    } else {
        play_refresh();
    }
}

send_free_parking = function(){
    $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/send_free_parking/', {
        player: $('#send_free_parking_player').val()
    });

    $('#send_free_parking_player').val("")

    bank_refresh();
}

set_balance = function(){
    if($('#set_player_bal_amount').val() == ""){
        alert("No amount entered");
        return;
    }
    if($('#set_player_bal_player').val() == null){
        alert("No player selected");
        return;
    }

    if ($('#set_player_bal_MK').text() == "K"){
        var amount = Number($('#set_player_bal_amount').val())
    } else {
        var amount = Number($('#set_player_bal_amount').val())*1000
    }
    var player = $('#set_player_bal_player').val()

    $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/set_balance/', {
        set_amount: amount,
        player_to_set: player,
    });

    $('#set_player_bal_player').val("")
    $('#set_player_bal_amount').val("")

    bank_refresh();
}

switch_lock = function(){
    $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/switch_lock/');

    bank_refresh();
}
```

And the HTML of the front-end that the banker uses

```
{% extends "SKELETON.html" %}
{% block content %}

<script>
    var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};


    var close_png_src = "{{ url_for('static', filename='./icons/close.png') }}"
    var edit_png_src = "{{ url_for('static', filename='./icons/edit.png') }}"

    $(document).ready(function(){
        bank_refresh();
        bank_background_checks();
    });
</script>

<!--Top Display-->
<div class="green_top">
    <div style="width: 20%; height; 100%; float: left;">
        <a href="/play/">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='./icons/play.png') }}" class="banker_switch">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="outer_rel" style="width: 80%; float: right;">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="inner">
                <a class="play_name_title">Bank {{ game_pin }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Body-->
<div style="width: 100%; height: 90%;">
    <!--Transfer Money-->
    <div style="height: 28%; width: 100%;" class="section_divider">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 30%; float: right;">
            <button id="send_money" class="green_btn play_go" onclick="javascript:send_money(true);">Go</button>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 50%; width: 70%; float: left;">
            <select id="send_money_player" class="user_select white_text">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Player</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 50%; width: 70%; float: left;">
            <input id="send_money_amount" type="number" class="play_amount_entry" placeholder="Amount">
            <a id="send_money_MK" class="white_text" style="height; 100%; width: 20%; font-size: 650%;" onclick="switch_char(this)">K</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Send Free Parking-->
    <div style="height: 15%; width: 100%;" class="section_divider">
        <div class="outer_rel" style="width: 30%; float: left;">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="inner">
                    <a id="free_parking" class="white_text" style="font-size: 300%; height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block; text-align: center;">Amount: 0K</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height; 100%; width: 70%; float: right;">
            <div style="height: 100%; width: 57%; float: left;">
                <select id="send_free_parking_player" class="user_select white_text" style="font-size: 300%;">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Player</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button id="send_free_parking" class="green_btn play_go" style="width: 43%; float: right;" onclick="javascript:send_free_parking();">Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Manage Players (edit names and remove-->
    <div style="height: 19%; width: 100%;" class="section_divider">
        <div id="active_players" class="in_scroll">
            <!--Individuals-->
            <!--<div style="width: 100%; height: 30%; display: block;">-->
                <!--<div style="width: 50%; height: 100%; margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 0px; float: left;">-->
                    <!--<div class="outer_rel">-->
                        <!--<div class="middle">-->
                            <!--<div class="inner">-->
                                <!--<a class="white_text" style="font-size: 350%; float: left;">Brent</a>-->
                            <!--</div>-->
                        <!--</div>-->
                    <!--</div>-->
                <!--</div>-->
                <!--<div style="width: 10%; height: 100%; float: right; margin-right: 15%;">-->
                    <!--<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='./icons/close.png') }}" style="height: 100%;">-->
                <!--</div>-->
                <!--<div style="width: 10%; height: 100%; float: right;">-->
                    <!--<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='./icons/edit.png') }}" class="banker_switch">-->
                <!--</div>-->
            <!--</div>-->

        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Edit Balance Of Player-->
    <div style="height: 18%; width: 100%;" class="section_divider">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 30%; float: right;">
            <button id="set_player_bal" class="green_btn" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 700%; font-family: Quicksand; border: none;" onclick="javascript:set_balance();">Go</button>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 50%; width: 70%; float: left;">
            <select id="set_player_bal_player" class="user_select white_text" style="font-size: 300%;">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Player</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 50%; width: 70%; float: left;">
            <input id="set_player_bal_amount" type="number" class="play_amount_entry" style="font-size: 300%;" placeholder="Amount">
            <a id="set_player_bal_MK" class="white_text" style="height; 100%; width: 20%; font-size: 400%;" onclick="switch_char(this)">K</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Who Starts First-->
    <div style="height: 8%; width: 100%;" class="section_divider">
        <div class="outer_rel">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="inner">
                    <a class="white_text" style="font-size: 300%; text-align: center; display: block;" onclick="javascript:who_starts_first();">Who starts first?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Lock and End-->
    <div style="height: 12%; width: 100%;" class="section_divider">
        <div class="green_btn" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; float: left;">
            <div class="outer_rel">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <a id="lock_button" class="play_bottom_btns" onclick="javascript:switch_lock();">Open</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="red_btn" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; float: right;">
            <div class="outer_rel">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <a class="play_bottom_btns" onclick="javascript:leave_prep('end the game?');">End</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Can anyone see what is causing this and how to fix it?

The developer hasn't updated it in nearly 3 years, so I assume he's discontinued it

Comment: I can't add the python script that runs as the server, but it can be viewed here:

https://github.com/brentvollebregt/monopoly-money/blob/master/run_server.py

Answer (score 1):

Lines 427-438 (https://github.com/brentvollebregt/monopoly-money/blob/9fc8f631746a6fdfb627b5b22f37f270113b48b8/run_server.py)

```
game = data['users'][request.cookies['id']]['game']
name = data['users'][request.cookies['id']]['name']

# Check if banker
if data['users'][request.cookies['id']]['type'] != "banker":
    return jsonify()

player_name = request.form['player_to_set']
balance = int(request.form['set_amount'])

data['games'][game]['players'][name]['bal'] = balance
data['games'][game]['logs'].append("Bank set balance of " + name + " to " + str(balance) + "K")
```

Notice that the target player name (form parameter) is stored in `player_name` and the executing player (cookie parameter) is stored in `name`, but the code then uses the variable `name` instead. This will always set the balance of the player executing the request, ie the banker.

Edit: It appears that this bug has now been fixed: https://github.com/brentvollebregt/monopoly-money/commit/7136b61f90e497d5ff5e0763a2f135941ad7ad79